# OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, dlib, pose-estimation

I am getting an overflow error sometimes signed integer greater than or less than maximum or minimum respectively.

My code for pose estimation:

```
import cv2
import dlib
import numpy as np
from imutils import face_utils

face_landmark_path = './shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat'

K = [6.5308391993466671e+002, 0.0, 3.1950000000000000e+002,
 0.0, 6.5308391993466671e+002, 2.3950000000000000e+002,
 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
D = [7.0834633684407095e-002, 6.9140193737175351e-002, 0.0, 0.0, -1.3073460323689292e+000]

cam_matrix = np.array(K).reshape(3, 3).astype(np.float32)
dist_coeffs = np.array(D).reshape(5, 1).astype(np.float32)

object_pts = np.float32([[6.825897, 6.760612, 4.402142],
                     [1.330353, 7.122144, 6.903745],
                     [-1.330353, 7.122144, 6.903745],
                     [-6.825897, 6.760612, 4.402142],
                     [5.311432, 5.485328, 3.987654],
                     [1.789930, 5.393625, 4.413414],
                     [-1.789930, 5.393625, 4.413414],
                     [-5.311432, 5.485328, 3.987654],
                     [2.005628, 1.409845, 6.165652],
                     [-2.005628, 1.409845, 6.165652],
                     [2.774015, -2.080775, 5.048531],
                     [-2.774015, -2.080775, 5.048531],
                     [0.000000, -3.116408, 6.097667],
                     [0.000000, -7.415691, 4.070434]])

reprojectsrc = np.float32([[10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
                       [10.0, 10.0, -10.0],
                       [10.0, -10.0, -10.0],
                       [10.0, -10.0, 10.0],
                       [-10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
                       [-10.0, 10.0, -10.0],
                       [-10.0, -10.0, -10.0],
                       [-10.0, -10.0, 10.0]])

line_pairs = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0],
          [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 4],
          [0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]

def get_head_pose(shape):
     image_pts = np.float32([shape[17], shape[21], shape[22], shape[26], shape[36],
                        shape[39], shape[42], shape[45], shape[31], shape[35],
                        shape[48], shape[54], shape[57], shape[8]])

_, rotation_vec, translation_vec = cv2.solvePnP(object_pts, image_pts, cam_matrix, dist_coeffs)

reprojectdst, _ = cv2.projectPoints(reprojectsrc, rotation_vec, translation_vec, cam_matrix,
                                    dist_coeffs)

reprojectdst = tuple(map(tuple, reprojectdst.reshape(8, 2)))

# calc euler angle
rotation_mat, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vec)
pose_mat = cv2.hconcat((rotation_mat, translation_vec))
_, _, _, _, _, _, euler_angle = cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix(pose_mat)

return reprojectdst, euler_angle


def main():
# return
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Unable to connect to camera.")
        return
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(face_landmark_path)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        face_rects = detector(frame, 0)

        if len(face_rects) > 0:
            shape = predictor(frame, face_rects[0])
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

            reprojectdst, euler_angle = get_head_pose(shape)

            for (x, y) in shape:
                cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

            for start, end in line_pairs:
                cv2.line(frame, reprojectdst[start], reprojectdst[end], (0, 0, 255))

            cv2.putText(frame, "X: " + "{:7.2f}".format(euler_angle[0, 0]), (20, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.75, (0, 0, 0), thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Y: " + "{:7.2f}".format(euler_angle[1, 0]), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.75, (0, 0, 0), thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Z: " + "{:7.2f}".format(euler_angle[2, 0]), (20, 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.75, (0, 0, 0), thickness=2)

        cv2.imshow("demo", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

getting an error in this line
"cv2.line(frame, reprojectdst[start], reprojectdst[end], (0, 0, 255))"
error:
"OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using lincolnhard's head-pose-estimation project on github.

**Use python2.7**. You will get that error when you use python3.